# What happens to a demon when their Possessed dies?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e

I've been reading up on the Possessed from the New World of Darkness book *Inferno*, but something isn't entirely clear to me. The Possessed are immortal but can still die of violence, but I cannot find what happens to the demon riding the Possessed afterwards. The book states what happens if the demon is exorcised (p. 123) and if the Possessed dies of burnout (p. 148), but not what happens if the Possessed dies of violence. Is the demon destroyed as well? Is it immediately cast back into the Inferno? Or does it linger just like in the other two cases? The last situation would make sense and fit the theme of the book in case the Possessed is slain by one of their victims or someone close to them (and in a fit of irony is then possessed by said demon), but I cannot find any rules that support such a situation. Have I missed something, or is it supposed to be up to the Storyteller to determine what happens in such a situation?

Answer (score 1):

How i solved this in one of my previous games was that the demon was indeed cast out of the body but not back into inferno, later to be able to possess a new victim.

I imagine this "rule" is up to the ST. But it is indeed a great question.